Whether "hockey" refers to ice hockey or field hockey
In the US and Canada, when simply saying "hockey", it is understood that one is referring to ice hockey.
Is it correct to say that in most (all?) other English-speaking countries, "hockey" refers instead to field hockey?

It does in the UK.

It depends. Fans of ice hockey in the UK often refer to it as "hockey". Australia seems to be similar to the UK. If you wanted to do any work yourself, you could look at naming of official bodies, leagues, etc. Is there any particular English-speaking country you're interested in? Because I don't think anyone's going to give you a list of usage in all 67 or so sovereign nations where English has some de jure or de facto status, to say nothing of expatriate communities elsewhere.

In the US, field hockey is not as popular a viewing sport as ice hockey and so field hockey games are rarely aired on TV here, whereas during ice hockey season there's always a game to watch. Field hockey in the US until relatively recently has been played at the scholastic and college level only by girls and women; very few high schools have boys field hockey teams but there have been girls field hockey teams for more than a century. As a result, of the people in the US who call field hockey "hockey" and ice hockey "ice hockey", most are women.

We don't often communicate in single words, so context will often be present. When it's not spelled out ("Going to a hockey game!"), even being in a certain country of region counts as context. The question is looking for an artificial clinical abstraction that isn't real language.

Yes, that seems a reasonable distinction.
Just looking as some URLs for national teams or organisations:

Ice Hockey

https://teamusa.usahockey.com/ (contrast https://www.usafieldhockey.com/)
https://www.hockeycanada.ca/


Field Hockey

https://www.greatbritainhockey.co.uk/ (contrast https://icehockeyuk.co.uk/)
https://hockey.ie/
https://www.hockey.org.au/
https://www.hockeynz.co.nz/
https://sahockey.co.za/
https://www.hockeyindia.org/
http://pakistanhockeyfederation.com/





Whether "hockey" refers to ice hockey or field hockey

Or "football" refers to the American pastime or the international game; or whether cricket refers to a game or an insect; or whether bat refers to a flying mammal or a club-like instrument found in some sports, etc.
The answer to your question is "context."

The question was Is it correct to say that in most (all?) other English-speaking countries, "hockey" refers instead to field hockey? // Try not to fixate on just the title and actually read the full question. The key to understanding a question is "context".

@user182601 The answer is also "the context". Any answer you would have given would have ended in the same conclusion.
